# Opening editor while the edit mode is vi in Readline

Tags: command-line, vi, readline

I have set my readline mode to be vi in my `~/.inputrc`

```
set editing-mode vi
```

I came to know that when you are in command mode, you can press <kbd>v</kbd> to open up current line in the editor defined in `$EDITOR` variable.

This works for me. But when I change the content in my editor, I am not sure how to get those changes back to my command line. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you make your changes just save and quit. The command will be executed after you quit. If you want to look at the command after you have executed it you can just push up.

If `EDITER=vim` or `EDITOR=vi` use `:wq` to save and quit

Comment: Thanks it works now. For some reason, I was not able to get it to work earlier.