# How can complete bash commands in default editor

Tags: bash, shell, vi, read-eval-print-loop

Some times when scripting or when working in a REPL of a language(node, scala e.t.c) I really miss vim. After entering in an REPL or may be in bash itself can I use my default editor to type the test/instructions/commands ?

Comment: This depends on the specific REPL -- ones based on libreadline *do* allow this; those based on editline may have similar capabilities, but it's still an individual question (does the repl for language X let you jump into an editor?), not something that has a generic answer.

Comment: Related: [Opening editor while the edit mode is `vi` in readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995399/opening-editor-while-the-edit-mode-is-vi-in-readline) -- obviously only correct for `readline`-based REPLs.

Comment: See for example https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html, documenting the capabilities of Python 2's REPL -- which *is* `readline`-based.

Comment: BTW, one thing that's important to understand -- once you started a programming language REPL (or any other foreground process), that REPL has full control over the terminal -- bash isn't doing anything at all anymore (except for waiting for its subprocess to exit), so bash's capabilities have no bearing on what the language REPL does or doesn't do.

Comment: Bash's readline has a bindable command [`edit-and-execute-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-edit_002dand_002dexecute_002dcommand-_0028C_002dxC_002de_0029), usually bound to `C-xC-e` (or `v` in vi mode, as linked to by Charles above).